# Derivation of average value of sample variance

Tags: statistics

I'm having some troubles understanding the following derivation.

Sample variance is defined as $$ s^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i - \bar x\right)^2 $$

The derivation goes as follows:

$$ \langle s^2 \rangle = \langle \left(x_i - \bar x\right)^2 \rangle
\\= \langle x_i^2 \rangle -2 \langle x_i \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j} x_j \rangle + \color{blue}{\frac{1}{n^2} \langle [\sum_{j} x_j]^2 \rangle}
\\= \langle x_i^2 \rangle - \frac{2}{n} \langle x_i^2 + \color{green}{\sum_{j \neq i} x_i x_j} \rangle + \color{blue}{\frac{1}{n^2} (n \langle x_i^2 \rangle + n(n-1) \langle x_i x_j \rangle _{i \neq j})}
\\= \langle x^2 \rangle - \frac{1}{n} \langle x^2 \rangle + \frac{(n-1)}{n} \langle x_i x_j \rangle_{i \neq j}
\\ = \frac{(n-1)}{n} ( \langle x^2 \rangle - \color{red}{\langle x_i x_j \rangle _{i \neq j}})
\\ = \frac{(n-1)}{n} ( \langle x^2 \rangle - \color{red}{\mu^2})
\\ = \frac{(n-1)}{n} \sigma^2 $$

The first thing I don't understand is the blue part - how do we get rid of this sum? Is it some identity that I miss?

Secondly (similar question, I think) — what happens with the sum that I colored green? Since I don't understand the part of the next line, I cannot tell what exactly this sum transforms into.

Thirdly — how to prove the part in red? Do we need some additional assumptions here?